# Why pass an empty object to jQuery's extend method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

jQuery has a very neat [`extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) method, which merges 2 objects into one.

On the [jQuery Plugins authoring page](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Defaults_and_Options) they show an example as follows:

```
var settings = $.extend({
    'location'         : 'top',
    'background-color' : 'blue'
}, options);
```

However, I've seen many plugins pass an empty object as the first parameter, like so:

```
var settings = $.extend({}, {
    'location'         : 'top',
    'background-color' : 'blue'
}, options);
```

As far as I can tell, these two do the exact same thing. The only difference would be if the `defaults` would have been stored in its own variable:

```
var defaults = {
    'location'         : 'top',
    'background-color' : 'blue'
},
settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
```

This way, you can always access your defaults without them being overridden by the `options`.

---

**Here's the question:** Why do so many plugin authors opt to pass an empty object  to `extend`, even when they don't store the defaults in a variable?

Am I missing something?

Comment: Seems pointless to me. It's making a populated one, copying it into an empty one, and discarding it. Your third example shows a valid reason. I'm guessing people do it because they don't think about what they're doing.

Comment: @amnotiam That's exactly what I'm thinking, but I've seen *so many* plugins do this. Clearly I'm missing something...

Comment: No, I think the trouble is that you're *getting* something.

Comment: Could be defensive coding I suppose. The *"what if someday I decide to store it in a variable and I forget..."* type of thing. If so, seems overly cautious to me.

Comment: Theory: somebody had the third form, realized they didn't need the variable and then "optimized" it into the second form.   Other plugins acquired the code because they used the "copy and modify" programming style.   Others saw it and just assumed there was a good reason for doing it that way.

Comment: yep, I agree with the other here. @JosephSilber you correctly understand what's happening here. The authors of the plugins that you are talking about are doin it rong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Possible reasons *(for the second example)*...

- Inherited ignorance... *(saw it done that way, and copied the practice)*
- Intrinsic ignorance... *(saw it done properly as in your last code block, but replaced the cached object with an on-the-fly object and didn't know that the empty object should be removed)*
- Global warming.
- Lack of attention to detail... *(similar to point 2, knows it isn't necessary but never really took the time to examine the code)*
- Global cooling.
- Overly defensive coding... *(afraid that the defaults may someday be reworked into a reusable object, and is afraid that the empty object won't be inserted at that time)*
- jQuery developers always do what the voices tell them ;-)

Overall, you're right. The middle object is created, copied to an empty object, then discarded. It's an unnecessary and wasteful practice.

Answer (score 10):

Extend is a very useful function to copy objects.

For example consider this:

```
foo = {'foo':'a'}
f = foo
f.foo = 'hello'
console.log(f)
    Object {foo="hello"}
console.log(foo)
    Object {foo="hello"}

f = $.extend({},foo)
f.foo = 'hello world'
console.log(f)
    Object {foo="hello world"}
console.log(foo)
    Object {foo="hello"}
```

So as you can see $.extend actually copied the object.

**EDIT**

The reason why the first parameter has to be an empty object is because of how `extend` works. Here is how jQuery defines `extend`:

```
jQuery.extend( target [, object1] [, objectN] )
   target    An object that will receive the new properties
             if additional objects are passed in or that will
             extend the jQuery namespace if it is the sole argument.
   object1   An object containing additional properties to merge in.
   objectN   Additional objects containing properties to merge in.
```

And additionally this phrase is important:

> Keep in mind that the target object (first argument) will be modified,
>   and will also be returned from $.extend().

So by passing the `{}` as first parameter, that empty object is extended and then returned.

Getting back to your example of `settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);`. If you would change it to `settings = $.extend(defaults, options);`, the settings will be identical however here the defaults will also be changed. Thats why you need the first argument to be `{}`.

Comment: Thanks for your update, but that is exactly what I described in my question. I understand the benefit of using an empty object in my 3rd example. What I'm trying to understand is the difference between my 1st and 2nd examples...

Comment: I guess I was not following your question. I like the community wiki answer as to why people like to write example #2.

Comment: I finally realize you are right when I accidentally ruin my first object in `$.extend{}` which I don't expect it to be changed.

Comment: Clear explanation; this should be marked as the solution.  This is the correct explanation

Answer (score 4):

Another way of putting what miki said:

```
var defaults = {
  one: 'foo',
  two: 'bar'
};

var options = {
  two: 'apples',
  three: 'bananas'
};

// The safe way to extend
var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

console.log( settings ); // {one: 'foo', two: 'apples', three: 'bananas'}
console.log( defaults ); // {one: 'foo', two: 'bar'}
console.log( options ); // {two: 'apples', three: 'bananas'}
console.log( settings === defaults ); // false

// Careless way to extend
var settings = $.extend(defaults, options);

console.log( settings ); // {one: 'foo', two: 'apples', three: 'bananas'}
console.log( defaults ); // {one: 'foo', two: 'apples', three: 'bananas'}
console.log( options ); // {two: 'apples', three: 'bananas'}
console.log( settings === defaults ); // true
```

Comment: Again, this is exactly what I outlined in my question. See my 3rd piece of code (and its preceding paragraph).

Comment: I guess I don't understand you're question then.  You ask: Why do so many plugin authors opt to pass an empty object to extend?  My answer is probably why. Storing your defaults in a variable won't prevent them from being overwritten.

Comment: My question is: why do so many plugin authors opt to pass an empty object to extend *even though they don't store the defaults in a variable*? I updated my question to clarify that.

Comment: Ah I see now, haha. That makes sense, and then yes I would agree with the other answer. Oh the vibrant community of jQuery plugin developers, there certainly a lot of wacky practices out there.