# What is the different between calling a function like this CH.home.init({}) or CH.home.init()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know if there is a different between calling a function like this

```
CH.home.init({})
```

or just calling it like a normal function?

```
CH.home.init()
```

Here's the context it's in:

```
var CH = CH || {};  
CH.core = function () {
        CH.home.init({});
    },
...
CH.home = function () {
    function init(a) { 
      $.extend(k, a)   
      ...

                var k = {
                        aDatas: null,
                        loaderId: "home",
                        transitionEase: "cubic-bezier(0.18, 0.11, 0.3, 1)",
                        timer: null,
                        nbRandom: 1,
                        ratioImg: .625,
                        opacityOff: .35,
                        speedOpacity: 400,
                        delayHome: 2500,
                        indexBkg: 0,
                        $logo: $("h1"),
                        $nav: $("nav"),
                        $lineH: $("span.lineH"),
                        $lineV: $("span.lineV"),
                        imgs: [{
                            src: "chny.jpg",
                            align: "top"
                        }, {
                            src: "ch.jpg",
                            align: "top"
                        }, {
                            src: "212.jpg",
                            align: "top"
                        }, {
                            src: "house.jpg",
                            align: "middle"
                        }]
                    };
```

Comment: Here `CH.home.init({});` you are passing an empty object when calling the function.

Comment: notice that the `init` you've shown to us in the "context" is a local function to `CH.home()`, not a property of `CH.home`

Comment: You can see the edit history for your post here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23197769/revisions. Questions are usually edited to correct spelling, grammar and formatting. The difference between your question and the one you linked to in your edit is that the context of the other question is much clearer. The author knows how `$.extend` works and is wondering what the benefit of passing an empty object as first argument is. You are simply asking what the difference between `randomFunc(a)` and `randomFunc()` is, which simply isn't a good question, since the answer is: Passing an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, the argument is different. In `init({})` you're passing an empty [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals), while in `init()` you're passing nothing. <s>Whether that makes a difference in the outcome depends on what the `init` function *does*, which you unfortunately have not shown to us.</s>

It does not seem to make a difference in your `init` function, where the parameter is used to [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) the `k` object. If nothing is passed, the `a` will be `undefined`, and `$.extend` will do nothing to `k` - just as much as when extending it with no keys.

Comment: OK I added a bit to my code. I understand, it extends the var = k; I do not understand the reason why. Is there any possibilitie to get access to this empty object?

Comment: see answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658512/why-pass-an-empty-object-to-jquerys-extend-method

Comment: @hamburger: But in that question, the order of the arguments is different. You're passing `a` (nothing, empty object, optional options) as the second argument to `$.extend`, not as the first.

Comment: I also think in my case it makes no sence to pass an object. I found this snipe somewhere and didn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

`CH.home.init({})` is calling `CH.home.init` with an empty object as a parameter, while `CH.home.init()` is calling  `CH.home.init` with no parameters