# understanding the usage of this instead of empty object inside $.extend

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys I was just going through the code of `parallax.js` and i came across the following line of code:

```
$.extend(this, DEFAULTS, options, data);
```

I have never seen `$.extend()` used like above, I have seen things like:

```
$.extend({}, DEFAULTS, options, data);
```

Well `this` in the above instance is a jQuery object afterall, so I don't think there is something wrong in doing the above, but can somebody tell me why particularly that is useful? An example will be really helpful, as I really have a very blury understanding of why the above is used instead of     `$.extend({}, DEFAULTS, options, data);` .

The line of code can be found **[HERE](https://github.com/wagerfield/parallax/blob/master/source/jquery.parallax.js#L67)**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As per the **[*jQuery documentation*](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)**, **extend will "...merge the contents of two or more objects together into first object**."

> When two or more object arguments are supplied to $.extend(),
>   properties from all of the objects are added to the target object.
>   Arguments that are null or undefined are ignored.

Target objects/first passed object will always be modified by use of extend and it is returned from the function.

**However if the objects states to be kept intact then we pass `{}` object as first argument.**

```
1 var object = $.extend({}, object1, object2,....,objectn);
```

---

A couple of points to be kept in mind always:

- Passing false for the first argument is not supported.
- Properties undefined are not taken into account. Properties inherited from the object's prototype will be copied over.
- Generally merge performed is by default not recursive in nature however by passing true for the first function argument, objects will be recursively merged.

**Specific to your case:**

When `.extend()` receives two or more objects, it takes the first object and adds to it the methods and variables defined in the other objects.

```
defaults = { size: 3 };
options = { height: 6 };
var opts = $.extend(defaults, options)
// 'defaults' receives the methods and variables defined in 'options'
// opts == defaults == { size: 3, height: 6 }
// options == { height: 6 };
```

If the first object is empty, it will add the methods and variables in a new object. This is useful when we want to group the methods defined in several objects without modifying any of them.

Like this:

```
 var opts = $.extend( {}, defaults, options)
// 'opts' gets all methods and variables defined in 'defaults' and 'options',
// neither of them get modified.
// opts == { size: 3, height: 6 }
// defaults == { size: 3 };
// options == { height: 6 };
```

Answer (score 0):

I am no export on the [`extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) method but what I do know makes me think this is the explanation:

The `$.extend({}, DEFAULTS, options, data);` version copies the defaults into an empty object see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658512/why-pass-an-empty-object-to-jquerys-extend-method?rq=1) for details on why people do this.

The `$.extend(this, DEFAULTS, options, data);` will copy the defaults into the object that `this` is referencing.

I could see this being used as a way to update the defaults/options/data of the object without having to specify every property that may have already been set, which is what the empty object version would force you to do in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

You said that `this` "...is a jQuery object afterall. Take a look at [line 489](https://github.com/wagerfield/parallax/blob/master/source/jquery.parallax.js#L489) in the source you referenced:

```
plugin = new Plugin(this, value);
```

Plugin is being used as a constructor function. That means that `this` is a reference to the object being constructed. As such, `$.extend` is being used to copy members into the object being constructed from `DEFAULTS`, `options` and `data` objects in order (so `options` overrides `DEFAULTS` and `data` overrides `options`).